# Standard terminology for the operator $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (b*c*d, a*c*d, a*b*d, a*b*c)$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, terminology, transformation

Is there a standard name for the operator $s(a,b,c,d) := (bcd, acd, abd, abc)$ ? More generally, $s(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = (z_1,\ldots,z_n)$, where $z_i = \prod_{j \ne i} x_j$.

Comment: None that I know of. Invent one if you need one.

Comment: There is the notion $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)\mapsto x_1 \cdots \hat{x_i}\cdots x_n$. This is used in group cohomology, among other things.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. Does this notion have a standard name ? Refs welcome.

Comment: No. There are too many different operators, to give  a name for each one.

Comment: I rephrase: What does the notion you mentioned mean / represent ? When / where does it appear ? What does is $\widehat x_i$ ? Thanks.

Comment: 1. It means $\prod_{j \ne i} x_j$, what you wrote above. 2. It appears in group cohomology for the explicit coboundary operator.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I having a hard time getting my hands on a reference (even via google). Is this for a specific type of group cohomology ?

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414081/coboundary-operators-1-cocycles-and-computing-cohomology) for example: are defined on the generators by the formula
$$d_n(g_0,\ldots,g_n)=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^n(g_0,\ldots,\widehat{g_j},\ldots,g_n)$$

Comment: A related map is the Veronese map (and its generalizations), which is given by $(x,y,z) \to (yz, xz, xy, x^2, y^2, z^2)$.

Comment: Also, the map $(x : y : z) \to (yz : xz : xy) $ is an often-used example of a birational map $\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P^2}$. You can look up Cremona Transformations if you are interested.